# Extra vertical offset after using \\

Tags: spacing

I want a simple title for my document that consists of 3 different parts.

Here is what I have:

```
\begin{Huge}
\textbf{Title part 1\\ \vspace{0.8cm}
    Title part 2\\ \vspace{0.8cm}
    Title part 3} \vspace{2cm}
\end{Huge}
```

which produces:

[image: different vertical offsets]

As you can see the offset between the first and the second part is larger than the one between 2 and 3, which is the desired `0.8cm`.

I found out that removing the `\\` after `Title part 2` leads to a correct offset of `0.8cm` between the first and the second part:

```
\begin{Huge}
\textbf{Title part 1\\ \vspace{0.8cm}
    Title part 2 \vspace{0.8cm}
    Title part 3}
\end{Huge}
```

[image: correct offset]

However, this, of course, removes the desired linebreak after part 2.

I also experimented with `\newline` and `\hfill \break` but without success.

**How can I get the three parts - each in a new line - evenly spaced (0.8cm)?**

### Edit

I am using `\linespread{1.5}` which seemed to also cause some trouble. It's my first time working with LaTeX so I don't know that much yet.

Anyway, the solution from @AboAmmar worked fine:

```
{\Huge\bfseries 
Title part 1\par\vspace{0.8cm}
Title part 2\par\vspace{0.8cm}
Title part 3\par 
}
```

Comment: It’s the other way around: the expected space is between lines 1 and 2 (interline skip plus 0.8cm). Between lines 2 and 3 the space is not 0.8cm. In general, however, there is no precise notion of vertical space between two lines, because of ascenders and descenders. Only the distance between baselines is independent on the characters actually present in the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{Huge}\bfseries
Title part 1 \vspace{0.8cm}

Title part 2 \vspace{0.8cm}

Title part 3

\end{Huge}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Or the more compact version:

```
{\Huge\bfseries 
Title part 1\par\vspace{0.8cm}
Title part 2\par\vspace{0.8cm}
Title part 3\par 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{Huge}
\noindent\textbf{Title part 1\\[0.8cm]
    Title part 2\\[0.8cm]
    Title part 3}\vspace{2cm}
\end{Huge}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    \end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why but you're solution didn't work for me.

Comment: With just this code?

Comment: When creating a new tex file and copy-pasting your whole code, it works fine. But when I tested your code in my file at the right place, it somehow didn't work.

Comment: It made no difference. I still had the bigger offset between part 1 and 2.

Comment: You should post a minimal example reproducing the problem. There must be something in the rest of you code that is responsible for this.

Comment: It's because I'm using `\linespread{1.5}`. Sorry for the inconvenience. It's my first time with LaTeX and I became a template from my school to work with.